# Spring-ws add interceptors not globally

Tags: java, spring, soap, spring-ws

I'm using @Configuration classes to config the endpoints, and need one with security and another without.

If I add interceptors they are aplied to both, i can't find a way to assign an interceptor only for one of them.

```java
@Override
public void addInterceptors(List<EndpointInterceptor> interceptors) {
    try {
        interceptors.add(mySecurityIniterceptor());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("No se puede inicializar el Interceptor.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare your Interceptor like my following example

```
public class MyInterceptor  implements SmartEndpointInterceptor {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldIntercept(MessageContext messageContext, Object endpoint) {
        if (endpoint instanceof MethodEndpoint) {
            MethodEndpoint methodEndpoint = (MethodEndpoint)endpoint;
            return methodEndpoint.getMethod().getDeclaringClass() == YourEndpoint.class; <--------Replace that with your endpoint that you wish to interpret
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleRequest(MessageContext messageContext, Object o) throws Exception {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleResponse(MessageContext messageContext, Object o) throws Exception {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleFault(MessageContext messageContext, Object o) throws Exception {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(MessageContext messageContext, Object o, Exception e) throws Exception {

    }
}
```

Don't forget to modify the line `YourEndpoint.class; <--------Replace that with your endpoint that you wish to interpret` in the above code.

Then register the Interceptor with

```
@Override
public void addInterceptors(List<EndpointInterceptor> interceptors) {
    try {
        interceptors.add(new MyInterceptor());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("No se puede inicializar el Interceptor.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Boug, but this method is for the mvc framework, not for webservice, `WsConfigurerAdapter`, in the method that I use the param is a `List<EndpointInterceptor>` not a `InterceptorRegistry`.

Comment: mmm... my interceptor is a `Wss4jSecurityInterceptor` I think that I can't do this. I will try some thing like that. Thanks!

Comment: In that case just do `public class MyInterceptor extends Wss4jSecurityInterceptor   implements SmartEndpointInterceptor `. Please don't forget to accept answer if you have solved your problem :D

Comment: I try again and with a little change in my implementation this works!
I add the interceptor in a class that extend WsConfigurationSupport and not WsConfigurerAdapter.
Thanks a lot.